# Действительно ли хорош Kali Linux

Tags: linux

Действительно ли хорош Kali Linux в аудите безопасности систем?Или же есть более удобные OS?

Comment: [help/dont-ask] считает, что подобные вопросы тут задавать не стоит.

Answer (score 4):

Kali Linux это дистрибутив Linux, в котором есть много готовых и удобных утилит. Он хорош в аудите тем, что у него есть много готовых библиотек и утилит для поиска возможных проблем. Так же есть много готовых "хаков" для проверки на старые, известные "дырки".

Так же это одна из самых больших аналогичных OS, но она не всесильная. То что она не может (список больше, это те которые пришли в голову):

1. Аудит Windows приложений. Хотя некоторые и можно проверять, но не все.
2. Аудит других ОС. Хотя можно частично проводить аудит ОС, но это не является целью Kali Linux.

Kali Linux больше для аудита сетевых систем подходит, но можно и применять для других целей тоже.